# How to deploy a Node JS API and React front end on one AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a project where I run Node JS that calls stored procedures to a MySQL database and returns data to a React project. I want to host these on one EC2 AWS instance. It's not going to be large scale so I don't want to do multiple instances and save money.

I followed [this](https://medium.com/@rksmith369/how-to-deploy-mern-stack-app-on-aws-ec2-with-ssl-nginx-the-right-way-e76c1a8cd6c6) tutorial but have not gotten anything to work. I was wondering if there was another way to do get this accomplished.

Nginx gives me this error: [error] 23823#23823: *25 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

[Here](https://github.com/laneherby/SavantLite.git) is a link to my current repo where both apps are in one folder

Comment: Are you receiving any logs or error messages? Stating where you are running into issues and/or what is being reported back to you will help people here answer your question.

Comment: nginx is giving me "[error] 23823#23823: *25 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream" and I get a 502 bad gateway

Comment: Your link leads to a 404 page. 

There should be other information with that error such as the ip address. Verify that the ports match. Also post your ```/etc/nginx/sites-available``` file.